# How do I make a div hide onclick and make it show when it's clicked again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, document-ready

I have this code:

```
<script>
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#thisclick, #thisclick2").click(function () {
            if ($('.example').is(":hidden")) {
                $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Hide/, 'Show'));
            } else {
                $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Show/, 'Hide'));
            }
            // Do it afterwards as the operation is async
            $(".example").hide();
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

The way the current code works is that if `#thisclick` is clicked it hides `#example`. Which is what I require but when `#thisclick` is clicked again i want it to show `#example`. Using the above code, it won't work.  What must I do to achieve this?

Comment: use [JQuery .hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [JQuery .show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have `$('#thisclick').slideToggle('slow');` instead of `$('#example').slideToggle('slow');`.

Comment: @kyle, I am sorry, I posted the old code.  I updated my question with the one I am currently using.

Comment: @JeffShaver He is trying to hide an element after clicking on a different element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to change your code to as follows to get it to work:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#thisclick").click(function () {
        $("#example").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a link to a quick sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/andyjmeyers/szmXp/

Comment: Thanks Andy.  It works fine but I have two id's that I am using.  It works whenever I click the second one but it won't work if I use the first one.  This is how i am using this line: $("#thisclick, #thisclick2").click(function () {

Comment: I updated the fiddle to include 2 buttons to both perform the same function call.  It looks like you are setting it up correctly $("#thisclick, #thisclick2").click(function () {})

Comment: Thanks.  That's same as what I updated your initial code too.  But it won't work the way it should.  Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Do you have an example that you might be able to share via JS fiddle or elsewhere so we can take a look?

Comment: What I posted is what i have minus the basic html.  The #example is actually an h3 class.  Could that be something that's interfering?

Comment: The element being h3 shouldn't make a difference.  It should still work.  I would try messing with it in the chrome dev tools like checking to make sure that  $("#thisclick, #thisclick2").length is 2.  If it is returning the correct elements, try putting a breakpoint in the click function and see if you get an error or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Are you expecting like

```
<button>This click</button>
<p style="display: none">Example</p>

<script>
$("button").click(function () {
$("p").toggle();
});
</script>
```

Please check it on http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/1107/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    (function ($) {
          $(document).ready(function() {
          $("#thisclick").click(function () {
             if ($('#example').is(":hidden")) {
                 $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Hide/, 'Show'));

             } else {
                 $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/Show/, 'Hide'));
             }
             // Do it afterwards as the operation is async
             $("#thisclick").slideToggle("slow");
             if($("#example").attr("isHidden") == "1")
                  $("#example").slideToggle("slow");
             $("#example").attr("isHidden","1");
          });
      });
        })(jQuery);
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("#thisclick").click(function () {
   if ($('#example').hasClass("hidden"))
   {
      $('#example').removeClass("hidden");
      $('#example').show();
   }
   else
   {
      $('#example').addClass("hidden");
   }
}
```

or more easily:

```
$("#thisclick").click(function () {
   $('#example').toggleClass("hidden");
}
```

define style":

```
.hidden
 { display:none;}
```